# How to use R optim function to determine a value required for multiple parts of another iterative function

Tags: r

I'm trying to determine a hydraulic parameter (water surface elevation, WSE) that results in my calculated stream discharge matching a measured discharge at a given location. I have lots of these locations to iterate through, so ideally creating a loop to run through all of my data. For now I'm just testing this out on a given cross section location.

What I want optim() to do is find the best WSE (water surface elevation), which feeds into other hydraulic equations (wetted area, wetted perimeter) to estimate stream discharge. Right now it seems that optim() is just giving me my discharge value. Guessing I just have the order of operations wrong or that I'm pointing optim() to the wrong thing? Any insight is super appreciated.

```
# make up some dummy data:
x <- seq(0, 50, length.out = 20)
z <- c(seq(100,60,length.out = 8), 58,56,56,58, seq(60,100, length.out = 8))
plot(x,z) # v-shaped stream channel cross section

#remove NAs (lots of these in my real data):
x <- x[!is.na(x)]
z <- z[!is.na(z)]

# Mannings N:
N <- 0.05

# Target Q (discharge, in cubic feet per second): 
Q <- 400

# Slope (ft/ft)
slope <- 0.004

# Create a function to minimize the difference between estimated and calculated Q:
Q.calc <- function(WSE){
  
  # calculate wetted area:
  wet.area <- vector(length = length(x))
  for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
    if(max(z[i],z[i+1]) > WSE){ # assign 0 to locations above WSE
      wet.area[i] <- 0
    } else {
      wet.area[i] <- (x[i+1] -x[i])*(WSE - (z[i+1] + z[i])/2)
    }
  }
  
  wet.area <- sum(wet.area) # sum across channel
  
  # calculate wetted perimeter:
  wet.perim <- vector(length = length(z))
  for(i in 1:(length(z)-1)){
    if(max(z[i],z[i+1]) > WSE) {  # assign 0 to locations above WSE
      wet.perim[i] <- 0
    } else {  # calculate perimeter for locations below WSE
      wet.perim[i] <- sqrt(((x[i+1]-x[i])^2)+((abs(z[i+1]-z[i])^2)))
    }
  }
  wet.perim <- sum(wet.perim) # sum across channel
  
  # hydraulic radius:
  hyd.radius <- wet.area/wet.perim
  
  # This is the equation we're actually 'optimizing':
  # Calculating when Q.calc = Q observed:  
  (1.49/N)*wet.area*hyd.radius^(2/3)*slope^0.5 - Q # since we're minimizing we 
  #subtract the observed Q so that optimal Q.calc = Q.obs ?? 
  
}

optim(par = mean(z), 
      fn = Q.calc, 
      lower = min(z), 
      upper = max(z),
      method = 'Brent',
      control = list(maxit = 100000))

$par
[1] 56

$value
[1] -400

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: I haven't tried to completely understand your code, but I have carried out some similar operations before and have a few suggestions. If you are optimizing only a single "parameter", you can use `optimize()` instead. If you stick with your above approach, to try to debug, you can try calling up `Q.calc()` directly with different values of `WSE` to make sure the residuals that are returned match what you expect. Lastly, separately removing NAs from x and y is risky, assuming they are paired variables. Instead, you can apply indexing to a data frame, use `subset()` or `na.omit()`.

Comment: @sashahafner the optimize() function totally worked, and I've also edited my code with the na.omit() call. The key to getting the WSE result that I actually wanted was to take the absolute value of my Q.calc equation versus the absolute minimum (some large negative number) so that the 'optimal' WSE resulted in calculated Q = observed Q. Thanks so much for your comment and suggestions!